# Как сделать меню вот такого типа?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Меню]

Как сделать отступы справа и слева, чтобы было такое ощущение, что меню в центре. Короче на картинке всё видно. Уже долго пробую и ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Выравнивайте с помощью flex либо grid

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background: whitesmoke;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.log-in {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="log-in">
      <button>Log in</button>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1140px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* justify-content space-around or between */

.wrap-menu {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

span {
  color: aqua;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*  отсутп слева Входа до пункта 4 */
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.right a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrap-menu">
  
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
      <li>Пункт 4</li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="right">
      <span>Вход и Регистрация</span>
      <a href="">Подать объявление</a>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Не хочу гадать с отступами. Незная никаких ширин контейнера и самого меню.
Отcтупы справа и слева делаются через margin-right / margin-left.

Само меню через flex в строку можно расположить. 
и смотря как тебе нужно justify-content: center / space-beetween / space-around. 
Если center выберешь то задай margin-left: - для входа и регистрации. 
Я space-between использовал чтобы в 2 стороны меню раскидать.

Comment: Используя flex можно обойтись без всяких отступов. Тем более в 100рх